# Node.js online server upload with mysql support

Tags: mysql, node.js, nodejitsu

I currently have developed a server in `node.js` (and respective client) which works without hassle. It uses `socket.io` and communicates with a `mysql` database to retrieve some info for certain messages.

The problem is that I tried uploading it online using `Nodejitsu`. The communication works without problem but when it's the the server's turn to send a query for the database nothing happens, the client just sits there.

Is there and issue with `nodejitsu`? Seeing that all other modules work except the communication with the a `mysql` database I had setup.

Note that when running the server in my computer and communicating via `localhost` everything works flawlessly.

Comment: Where is your mysql database hosted?

Comment: @Vsevolod Goloviznin over at http://www.freemysqlhosting.net/